# Processing speed acting strange

Tags: vb.net, cpu, processor

I got this simple question which confused me a bit. I got 2 processors Both of which can individually do 1 billion operations in 33.0360723.
Yet both of them together do the operations in 27.4996964.

This makes no sense for me, if the time for a task for one processor is X, then should it not be X/2 for both of them together?

My code:

```
Function calc(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal result As String)
    Math.Sqrt(i)
    Return True

End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim result As String = Nothing


    Dim starttime As TimeSpan
    starttime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
    For i = 0 To 1000000000
        calc(i, result)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("A single processor runs 1 billion operations in: ")
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - starttime)



    starttime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay

    Parallel.For(0, 1000000000, Function(i) calc(i, result))

    Console.WriteLine("All your processors run 1 billion operations in: ")
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - starttime)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

PS: I did the code for this in VB.net.

Comment: Show us code! Most likely your example has far more overhead on synchronization of the two processors than actual work.

Comment: Is the 2nd processor a hyper-threading virtual processor?

Comment: This is a good question and should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If a person can walk 2 miles in 30 minutes, how long will it take 2 people to walk the same 2 miles?

All jokes aside, the documentation at MSDN says:Executes a for (For in Visual Basic) loop in which iterations **MAY** run in parallel. the keyword here is **MAY**.

You are letting the CLR do the work and experience says that .net CLR does not always work the way you thought it would.

In my case (copy-pasted the code) single processor - 21.495 seconds, all processors: 7.03 seconds. I have an i7 870 CPU on 32 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Your joke would actually be invalid, each person would have to walk 1 mile in order to walk 2 miles of distance.

Comment: At least it does not optimize the loops into nops (since the result is never used--though that would also require recognizing that no exceptions are possible [the values being non-negative]). Compilers (and even more so run-time environments) can break microbenchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

In `Parallel.For` the order of iteration is not necessarily in the same order of the loops.

Also what your function does is `sqrt(i)` which means one processor might be doing `sqrt(smallernumbers)` and   another `sqrt(largernumbers)` .

Simple answer is the work done by each processor is not exactly half of the whole work you gave them and so they are not likely to be equal.

One processor might have done more work and other might have completed its work and wait for the other. Or one of the processor might have been `preempted` by the operating system to do some important stuff while your working thread may have been waiting.